# Print elements of array and add them in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, addition

In this section,how can display the elements of an array?

```js
var cars = ["1", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var text = "";
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  total += parseInt(cars[i]);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: This is what your code appears to be doing already. If you're having issues with it we need to know more about what specifically it does/does not do, and also see any related HTML and CSS so we can re-create the problem

Comment: Please note that `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;` overwrites `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;`

Comment: okay,Can I display both the elements and their sum at the same time?

Comment: Do you mean display *all* the values in the array? Again - please be much clearer when describing what you're attempting to achieve. It would really help if you edited the question to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is this: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;`

At first you set the `innerHTML` to `text` and after the next loop you set it to `total`. Thats why you've got the sum.

You could set the `innerHTML` to both, like i did here:

```js
var cars = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var text = "";
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  total += parseInt(cars[i]);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text + total;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```